# React propType cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Using propTypes to validate props gives the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined.
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined.

The code in question is at the bottom of the snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import ProjectItem from './ProjectItem';

class Projects extends React.Component {
    
    deleteProject(title) {
      this.props.onDelete(title);
    }

    render() { 
      let projectItems;

      if (this.props.project) {
        projectItems = this.props.project.map(project => {
            return (
                <ProjectItem key={project.title} project={project} onDelete={this.deleteProject.bind(this)}  />
            )
        });
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="Projects">
          {projectItems}
        </div>    
      );    
    }

}

Projects.propTypes = {
  projects: React.PropTypes.string,
  onDelete: React.PropTypes.func
}
```

Comment: What is your react version?

Answer (score 27):

You need to install the `prop-types` package and then add the import statement

`import PropTypes from prop-types;`

at the top of your class.

[The PropTypes have been moved from React to their own package `prop-types`.](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, this is only applicable for React version  15.5 and above.

Comment: You should note that this is only necessary for versions >= React v15.5

Comment: @linas mnew Yes you are right. But I assumed as much based on the errors the OP has posted and the code.

Answer (score 2):

As palsrealm mentioned, you need to add the prop-types package, and then remove React before Proptypes. The following should work:

```
Projects.propTypes = {
   projects: PropTypes.string,
   onDelete: PropTypes.func
}
```