# React-native and PropType problem: "Cannot read property 'string' of undefined

Tags: react-native, npm

I have a React-native project with react-native version ^0.71.6 and react-native-prompt ^1.0.0, among others. I also have deprecated-react-native-prop-types with version ^4.1.0. When I try to run the app into the Android, I have this error:

"Cannot read property 'string' of undefined"

The origin of the problem seems to be the file \node_modules\react-native-prompt\src\Prompt.js, which has this code inside:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  Modal,
  Platform,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

export default class Prompt extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
```

Where 'title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,' is the issue.

I have seen this link, but I could not resolve the problem
[React propType cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748441/react-proptype-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Here is my package.json. I did npm install and then npm run start

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^11.1.3",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^11.1.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.9",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.9",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.10",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.71.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "deprecated-react-native-listview": "^0.0.8",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.1.0",
    "npm": "^9.6.4",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "radio-button-react-native": "^1.1.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.6",
    "react-native-actions-sheet": "^0.8.29",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.17.3",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-chooser": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.2.0",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-flip-toggle-button": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^14.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.6.2",
    "react-native-prompt": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.14.0",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-side-menu-updated": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-simple-modal-picker": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-sketch": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-router": "^6.10.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "resolve-url": "^0.2.1",
    "source-map-resolve": "^0.6.0",
    "source-map-url": "^0.4.1",
    "uglify-js": "^3.17.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.35",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Any suggestion?